# How do multiply an array of ints to result in a single number?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, math, cryptography

So I have a single int broken up into an array of smaller ints. For example, `int num = 136928` becomes `int num[3] = {13,69,28}`. I need to multiply the array by a certain number. The normal operation would be `136928 * 2 == 273856`. But I need to do `[13,69,28] * 2` to give the same answer as `136928 * 2` would in the form of an array again - the result should be

```
for(int i : arr) {
  i *= 2;
  //Should multiply everything in the array
  //so that arr now equals {27,38,56}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated on how to do this (also needs to work with multiplying floating numbers) e.g. `arr * 0.5` should half everything in the array.

For those wondering, the number has to be split up into an array because it is too large to store in any standard type (64 bytes). Specifically I am trying to perform a mathematical operation on the result of a sha256 hash. The hash returns an array of the hash as `uint8_t[64]`.

Comment: Think back to your early days of learning multiplication and track the "carries" when you overflow.

Comment: Mind you in this case multiplying by two is can be accomplished by shifting a bit through your array. Still need to carry the bit shifted out into the next byte, mind you.

Comment: You should iterate from the end instead of the beginning, since overflow carries in that direction.

Comment: Since you gave the result of multiplication in your comment, it would seem you already know how to do the multiplication. So all you have to do is translate what you did into C++.

Comment: *"(also needs to work with multiplying floating numbers) e.g. `arr * 0.5`"*. How about `arr * 0.1234` ? Do you expect floating result ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Not floating result - should return an int so ```int x = 6 * 0.34;``` should end up being ```x == 2```.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) instead. Specifically, the `cpp_int` type, which is a representation of an arbitrary-sized integer value.

```
//In your includes...
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
//In your relevant code:
bool is_little_endian = /*...*/;//Might need to flip this
uint8_t values[64];
boost::multiprecision::cpp_int value;
boost::multiprecision::cpp_int::import_bits(
    value, 
    std::begin(values), 
    std::end(values), 
    is_little_endian
);
//easy arithmetic to perform
value *= 2;
boost::multiprecision::cpp_int::export_bits(
    value, 
    std::begin(values), 
    8, 
    is_little_endian
);
//values now contains the properly multiplied result
```

Theoretically this should work with the properly sized type `uint512_t`, found in the same namespace as `cpp_int`, but I don't have a C++ compiler to test with right now, so I can't verify. If it does work, you should prefer `uint512_t`, since it'll probably be faster than an arbitrarily-sized integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need multiplying with / dividing by two (2) then you can simply shift the bits in each byte that makes up the value.

So for multiplication you start at the left (I'm assuming big endian here). Then you take the most significant bit of the byte and store it in a temp var (a possible *carry bit*). Then you shift the other bits to the left. The stored bit will be the least significant bit of the next byte, after shifting. Repeat this until you processed all bytes. You may be left with a single carry bit which you can toss away if you're performing operations modulo 2^512 (64 bytes).

Division is similar, but you start at the right and you carry the least significant bit of each byte. If you remove the rightmost bit then you calculate the "floor" of the calculation (i.e. three divided by two will be one, not one-and-a-half or two).

---

This is useful if

1. you don't want to copy the bytes or
2. if you just need bit operations otherwise and you don't want to include a multi-precision / big integer library.

Using a big integer library would be recommended for maintainability.